# Probing interactions by multiple comparisons between factor variables in ordinal regression, using ordinal::clm

Tags: r, statistics, regression

I simulated some data below that involves a 3 (experimental condition) x 3 (political affiliation) two-way interaction. I can run the overall model using `ordinal::clm()`. How can I get all multiple comparisons for this? Or, at least, the effect of `economy` and `race` over the control conditions for each political subgroup. I am trying to automate this, so creating a long matrix of contrasts is not preferable. `ordinal::clm()` objects have `vcov` and `coefficients` associated with them, so this should be possible. I have not had this work with `glht` or `emmeans`.

---

#### Code

```
## prepare ----------
library(Hmisc)
library(ordinal)
set.seed(1839)
## gen dat ----------
democrats       <- cut2(c(rnorm(80), rnorm(80, .4), rnorm(80, .6)), g = 5)
unaffiliated    <- cut2(c(rnorm(80), rnorm(80), rnorm(80, .5)), g = 5)
republicans     <- cut2(c(rnorm(80), rnorm(80, -.5), rnorm(80)), g = 5)
outcome         <- factor(c(democrats, unaffiliated, republicans))
levels(outcome) <- c("very negative", "somewhat negative", "neutral", 
                     "somewhat positive", "very positive")
condition       <- c(rep("control", 80), rep("economy", 80), rep("race", 80))
condition       <- as.factor(rep(condition, 3))
party           <- factor(c(rep("democrats", 240), 
                            rep("unaffiliated", 240),
                            rep("republicans", 240)))
dat             <- data.frame(outcome, condition, party)
## crosstb ----------
xtabs <- lapply(levels(dat$party), function(i) {
  round(prop.table(table(
    dat$outcome[dat$party == i], dat$condition[dat$party == i]
  )), 2)
})
names(xtabs) <- levels(dat$party)
## analyze ----------
mod <- clm(outcome ~ condition * party, data = dat)
xtabs
summary(mod)
```

---

#### Output

```
$democrats

                    control economy race
  very negative        0.10    0.06 0.03
  somewhat negative    0.08    0.08 0.05
  neutral              0.08    0.07 0.05
  somewhat positive    0.03    0.06 0.11
  very positive        0.04    0.07 0.09

$republicans

                    control economy race
  very negative        0.05    0.11 0.03
  somewhat negative    0.07    0.07 0.07
  neutral              0.04    0.09 0.07
  somewhat positive    0.08    0.05 0.08
  very positive        0.09    0.02 0.09

$unaffiliated

                    control economy race
  very negative        0.07    0.08 0.05
  somewhat negative    0.08    0.08 0.05
  neutral              0.07    0.08 0.05
  somewhat positive    0.06    0.06 0.08
  very positive        0.06    0.04 0.10
```

---

```
formula: outcome ~ condition * party
data:    dat

 link  threshold nobs logLik   AIC     niter max.grad cond.H 
 logit flexible  720  -1130.74 2285.47 4(0)  1.92e-12 3.8e+02

Coefficients:
                                   Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
conditioneconomy                     0.6492     0.2829   2.295 0.021725 *  
conditionrace                        1.2790     0.2820   4.535 5.77e-06 ***
partyrepublicans                     1.0089     0.2873   3.512 0.000444 ***
partyunaffiliated                    0.5064     0.2809   1.803 0.071371 .  
conditioneconomy:partyrepublicans   -1.7765     0.4038  -4.400 1.08e-05 ***
conditionrace:partyrepublicans      -1.1987     0.3998  -2.998 0.002714 ** 
conditioneconomy:partyunaffiliated  -0.9094     0.3968  -2.292 0.021905 *  
conditionrace:partyunaffiliated     -0.5367     0.3981  -1.348 0.177568    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Threshold coefficients:
                                Estimate Std. Error z value
very negative|somewhat negative  -0.8056     0.2060  -3.912
somewhat negative|neutral         0.2176     0.2026   1.074
neutral|somewhat positive         1.0791     0.2067   5.220
somewhat positive|very positive   2.1167     0.2176   9.727
```

---

#### Error using glht

```
> glht(mod, mcp(condition = "Tukey"))
Error in linfct[[nm]] %*% C : 
  requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments
```

---

#### Temporary solution

This works, but does not correct for multiple comparisons:

```
lapply(levels(dat$party), function(i) {
  cfs <- summary(clm(outcome ~ condition * relevel(party, i), data = dat))$coef
  cfs[grepl("^[A-Za-z]+$", rownames(cfs)), ]
})
```

Comment: What did you try in **emmeans**? It looks like this should work: `emm = emmeans( mod, ~ condition*party); pairs(emm, by = “condition”); pairs(emm, by = “party”)`

Comment: @rvl I was concerned with the degrees of freedom being infinite

Comment: Basically all analyses of ordinal data use asymptotic tests (e.g. z tests instead of t tests), which is another way of saying the df are infinite. BTW, see the vignette section https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/sophisticated.html#ordinal for an example where all the various `mode`s for `clm` models are explored.

Comment: @rvl I don't know how I missed that vignette! Thank you very much.